# Removing the extra top space in CoordinatorLayout- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I am trying to use `BottomSheetBehavior` to make a layout similar to what google maps is providing. I am successful in using the `BottomSheetBehavior` and create slide up layout. The problem I am having now is `CordinatorLayout` takes extra space even when my layout is collapsed. 
Below is a screenshot of my layout.

- White background in my main activity layout
- Pink is my collapsed layout with peekHeight
- And the grey background is the one which should be transparent but takes the extra space.

[image]
[image]

My main layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/sample_coordinator" />
</FrameLayout>
```

CordinatorLayout with BottomSheetBehavior

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use CoordinatorLayout in your activity layout.
Then in your bottom sheet layout insert these lines:

```
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="Xdp"
```